# How to automatically create a comment on CREATE in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-10

I would like to create a trigger which gets fired once a table is created in a schema. This trigger should add a comment to the newly created table, something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger 
   AFTER CREATE ON my_schema
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_comment;
```

With `add_comment` doing somthibg like:

```
...
BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
      COMMENT ON TABLE ' || new_table || ' IS ''Created by ' || CURRENT_USER || ' on ' || CURRENT_TIME ''';
   ';
```

However, it seems I can only add triggers on table level. How could I achieve to add comments to newly created tables in pure Postgres?

Comment: You want what Postgres calls an *event trigger*.  The subject is rather detailed, so start with the documentation:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-definition.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [`EVENT TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/event-triggers.html).

First create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_create_table_comment() RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj record;    
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() INTO obj;
  EXECUTE 'COMMENT ON TABLE ' || obj.object_identity || ' IS ''Created by ' || SESSION_USER || ' on ' || NOW() || '''';
END;
$$;
```

Then attach it to an `EVENT TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_table ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE','CREATE TABLE AS')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_create_table_comment();
```

After you create a table it will be triggered:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int);

SELECT schemaname,tablename,tableowner,description
FROM pg_tables t
LEFT JOIN pg_description d ON d.objoid = t.tablename::regclass::oid
WHERE tablename = 'foo';
    
 schemaname | tablename | tableowner |                    description                    
------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------
 public     | foo       | jones      | Created by jones on 2021-04-10 20:22:22.174874+02
```